# Throwing e.StackTrace doesn't show line number error in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

i have this code:

```
 using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
{
try{
    ...
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
      throw new Exception(e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

on my local instance of acumatica, it shows the error message and the line number,
in the cloud however, it doesn't show the line number (only the error message). i want to know how to get the line number error to fix my customization.
i already added the .pdb files in the customization package.

Comment: Can you check if debug is set to true in web.config? (<compilation debug=”true”/>). Note: you shouldn't leave it like that in production.

Comment: I already solved it by adding something like 
throw new Exception(e.StrackTrace.substring(e.StackTrace.Length - 30));

my hunch is it deletes "Line" and so on, so i figured just get the last few portions to show what line number the error occurred. 

yeah. it's on a test site. I'll still remove it after fixing the bug though.

Comment: By the way, exceptions get logged in Help->Trace with full stack trace available there.

Comment: Please add an answer to it and flag it as accepted - you can answer your own questions without any problems on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i just forgot to upload the .pdb file